# Powershell remove multiple shared mailboxes from multiple users

Tags: powershell, office365

Right now I have a function that removes multiple shared emails from a single user. But, I'd like to be able to specify multiple users that also need the multiple shared emails removed from their accounts as well. I can't think of a good way to do this?

Here is what I have so far and it works, but I can only specify one user on the -user parameter.

````
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$address,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$user
    )
    foreach ($mailbox in $address) {
        Remove-MailboxPermission `
            -Identity $mailbox `
            -AccessRights FullAccess `
            -Confirm:$false `
            -User $user

        Remove-RecipientPermission `
            -Identity $mailbox `
            -AccessRights SendAs `
            -Confirm:$false `
            -Trustee $user

        Set-Mailbox $mailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{remove = "$user" }
    }
} #function Remove-SharedMailbox```
````

Comment: Make `$user` of type `[string[]]` and create a nested loop in your current loop. Should be all you need.

Comment: That was what I was thinking, but I was unsure how to implent it. I'll test around that. Thanks.

Comment: If there's no answer posted by the time I wake up (currently on my phone) I will help. Good night man:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment:

```
function Remove-SharedMailbox {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$address,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string[]]$user
    )
    foreach ($mailbox in $address) 
    {
        foreach ($account in $user)
        {
            Remove-MailboxPermission `
                -Identity $mailbox `
                -AccessRights FullAccess `
                -Confirm:$false `
                -User $account

            Remove-RecipientPermission `
                -Identity $mailbox `
                -AccessRights SendAs `
                -Confirm:$false `
                -Trustee $account

            Set-Mailbox $mailbox -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{remove = $account }
        }
    }
}
```

it's ultimately the same logic you're already using just in a nested loop. Just made `$user` to accept an array of *strings* by casting `[string[]]` to it. The nested loop iterates through the users passed to it using `$account`.